# why user.Identity.Name is blank after logging in? Asp.net mvc 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, session

I am writing an asp.net MVC 2.0 application, and I need to get username after the user logs in and pass it to other function. I tried that by simply modifying the standard LogOn method for AccountController, here is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {

                FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                using (ShopController newCtrl = new ShopController())
                {
                    if (Session["TempCart"] != null)
                    {

                        newCtrl.CreateShoppingCartFromSession((Cart)Session["TempCart"], User.Identity.Name);
                    }
                }
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

The problem is that even though the user is logged in successfully, the "User.Identity.Name" is blank, and I don't know why...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forms authentication methods set an authentication cookie which gets read and processed for the first time on the next request, thus the `User.Identity` becomes available only from the next request.

In this method you will either have to do a redirect first or use your `model.UserName`.